# How to combine multiple trained models into one and use it to predict on the test set?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, model

I have a time series data frame with 100 rows and 1000+ columns. The columns are independent of each other.  I am running the ARIMA model on each of these columns. So, it is like running 1000+ ARIMA analysis.

I have written a piece of code that loops through the columns of the training set and fits the ARIMA model on every column as per the p,d,q parameters provided. Although, it looks like as the model trains further through the columns, it forgets what was learnt before and only uses the training results from the last trained column to predict on test. (Which is causing the predictions to overfit on the test set).

Is there a way I can combine the learnings of all the trained models together and use it to make predictions on my test set?

Sample Data frame looks like:

```
date                        Col 1     Col 2     Col 3      Col 4
2001-07-21 10:00:00+05:00    45          51       31         3  
2001-07-21 10:15:00+05:00    46          50       32         3
2001-07-21 10:30:00+05:00    47          51       34         7
2001-07-21 10:45:00+05:00    50          50       33         9
2001-07-21 11:00:00+05:00    55          51       32         8
2001-07-21 11:15:00+05:00    52          73       34         11
2001-07-21 11:30:00+05:00    51          72       30         14
```

The code I have implemented is:

```
#training set inclues all columns except the last and test set includes only last column.
train = df.iloc[:, :-1]
test = df.iloc[:,-1:]


order = (1,2,3) # <- plug-in p, d, q here 

for col in train.columns:
  model = ARIMA(train[col], order = order)  #training every column in training set
  model = model.fit()
model.summary()

predictions = model.predict(len(test))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this problem is possible to solve, as you've framed it.

Suppose you have a great machine learning model, and it extracts every possible piece of information from columns 1 through N-1.

This model still does not know the following:

- For column N, what order of magnitude value should be predicted? Is this a variable like GDP, which should have an answer in the range of a trillion? Is this a variable like percent unemployment, which should have an answer in the range of 0-100?
- Is column N generally increasing over time?
- Is column N generally decreasing over time?
- Is column N seasonally correlated?

> The columns are independent of each other.

Unless there's some reason to think that the columns of this dataframe ought to be correlated over time, the other columns aren't helping you forecast at all, and you should just get rid of them.

But, maybe the other columns *are* correlated with your Y variable. In that case, I'd suggest the following train/test split:

1. Take the first 2/3 of the rows of your dataset. This is the train set.

   Within the train set, the columns from 1 to N - 1 are your X_train. The column N is your Y_train.
2. Take the last 1/3 of the rows of your dataset. This is the test set.

   Within the test set, the columns from 1 to N - 1 are your X_test. The column N is your Y_test.

Use the X variables as an exogenous input to ARIMA. Most ARIMA libraries support this. I recommend [pmdarima](http://alkaline-ml.com/pmdarima/index.html), as it's the most user-friendly.

Fit the model on your train set.

Predict on your test set to validate particular choices of p, d, or q. Note that your estimate of accuracy will be biased upward. (You can avoid this by splitting into train, test, validate, but you may not have the data size to do this.)